# Why this error turns out when i tried to check an addon that i installed

Tags: python, add-on

this error turns out when i tried to check to activate an addon that i installed, this addon its this one from here https://github.com/CGCookie/retopology-contours i am using b3d 2.78a how can this error be solved? [image]

Comment: looks like you are missing the library dependency https://github.com/CGCookie/retopology-lib

Comment: @rob but how? i tried installing from file those "libs", and still i cant activate the addon

Comment: sadly the repo says the addon is no longer supported. Is the error still reporting the same missing lib? It maybe that it is just too old and unmaintained. Try looking around for an alternative.